# What is the best way to round a float in elixir

Tags: math, floating-point, elixir, elixir-iex

I am trying to round a `Float` in elixir to 2 decimal places.

If I have the number `12.555`, I would like my rounding function to return `12.56`

I originally thought that the [`Float.round`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#round/2) was what I wanted but this function does not always return the answer I would like.

For example...

```elixir
iex()> Float.round(12.555, 2)
12.55
```

I know that I can get this done with a makeshift function but I thought that there must be a better solution.

My current solution is...

```elixir
iex()> round(12.555 * 100) / 100
12.56
```

This does the job but like I said, I just wanted to know if there was a better solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with Elixir, but with IEEE 754 floating point numbers; see also https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html#round/2

Comment: @coproc please feel free to update the flags if you think that they are not accurate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because of the way floating point numbers work, if you want precision, including controlling [rounding algorithms](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.Context.html#module-rounding-algorithms), you need to use a library such as [Decimal](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html):

```elixir
12.555
|> Decimal.from_float()
|> Decimal.round(2)
```

Output:

```elixir
#Decimal<12.56>
```

You can then use functions like [`Decimal.to_string/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#to_string/2) for printing or [`Decimal.to_float/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#to_float/1), but beware that `to_float/1` is also an imprecise operation and could fail.

Answer (score 4):

Float.ceil/2 might help you with this if you don't want to use a library

```
iex> 12.555 |> Float.ceil(2)        
12.56
```

Comment: Not if you need sensible decimal behaviour. `Float.ceil(0.2, 1)` and `Float.ceil(0.3, 1)` both produce `0.3`, for example. https://floating-point-gui.de/